# How to use Numpy reshape?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have this data:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2007-01-03,12.160000,12.750000,11.530000,12.040000,12.040000,0
2007-01-04,12.400000,12.420000,11.280000,11.510000,11.510000,0
2007-01-05,11.840000,12.250000,11.680000,12.140000,12.140000,0
2007-01-08,12.480000,12.830000,11.780000,12.000000,12.000000,0
2007-01-09,11.860000,12.470000,11.690000,11.910000,11.910000,0
2007-01-10,12.340000,12.500000,11.430000,11.470000,11.470000,0
2007-01-11,11.420000,11.480000,10.500000,10.870000,10.870000,0
2007-01-12,10.930000,10.930000,10.140000,10.150000,10.150000,0
2007-01-16,10.640000,10.890000,10.400000,10.740000,10.740000,0
2007-01-17,10.900000,10.900000,10.350000,10.590000,10.590000,0
2007-01-18,10.650000,11.040000,10.450000,10.850000,10.850000,0
2007-01-19,10.800000,11.030000,10.240000,10.400000,10.400000,0
2007-01-22,10.770000,11.080000,10.620000,10.770000,10.770000,0
2007-01-23,10.770000,10.940000,10.220000,10.340000,10.340000,0
```

I have this code to run some time series predictions

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import LSTM
df = pd.read_csv("^VIX.csv")
df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(['Date'], drop=True)
split_date = pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01')
df =  df['Adj Close']
train = df.loc[:split_date]
test = df.loc[split_date:]
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = train.plot()
test.plot(ax=ax)
plt.legend(['train', 'test']);
```

so far so good, yet when running

```
# scale train and test data to [-1, 1]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
train_sc = scaler.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = scaler.transform(test)
```

I am getting an error:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[12.04
>   11.51     12.14     ... 16.08     17.290001 18.209999]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single
>   feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Although this is the original code, looks like the reshape is not done correct and I  am missing something out with the numpay reshape.

What should I fix in the reshape?
thanks!

Comment: So is this supposed to be a single feature problem, or a single sample?  Do you know the difference?  Let's also verify what `train` and `test` are?. Numpy array or pandas Series?  Shape?  Dtype?

Comment: When you get `shape` errors in `numpy` (and pandas) you need to check shapes, actual versus expected.  If you don't know what shape (or at least number of dimensions) an array should have at a specific point in the code, you don't understand your code.  Is this your own code, or is it from some tutorial or example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to your particular case:

```
train_sc = scaler.fit_transform(train.values.reshape(-1, 1))
test_sc = scaler.transform(test.values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy: `test` is empty, hence `scaler.transform` fails. Change:

```
split_date = pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01')
```

to e.g.

```
split_date = pd.Timestamp('2007-01-10')
```

to see it working.